# How to read an environment variable from an xml on the start of Tomcat?

Tags: java, xml, azure, tomcat, environment-variables

I'm working with an Azure Web App and I have some application settings set in the configuration part and I read them as Environment variables. I don't have any problem to read them through code, but I also have an xml(Application Insights configuration file) that needs to read a value(InstrumentationKey) from an environment variable at the start of the app but I can't find a way to read it.

Is there anyway to do it? I've seen some people adding a system property at the start of the app through Catalina but I really can't make it work.

I'm working with Java and Azure Web App on a Linux Server with Tomcat 9.0.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found out that there is a fastest way to do it, Application Insights SDK look for the key by default in the environment variables before looking for it in the configuration file so there is no need to do anything than deleting the key from the configuration file and adding the right environment variable for the key("APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY").

I also found out a way to fast fix it before finding this answer, I was manually adding the key into the xml file on the start of the app after reading it from the environment variables(just a small patch).